# Cannot install golang library wsarecv: An existing connect ion was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: go

I cannot get golang library by command
`go install  github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.4.0`
It show error :

> go: github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.4.0: github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.4.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/@v/v1.4.0.info": read tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:xx->74.125.200.141:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

But when go to the link 'https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/@v/v1.4.0.info' it show normal:

[image]

when I use `go mod tidy` it have same error

> github.com/xesina/golang-echo-realworld-example-app/handler tested by
> github.com/xesina/golang-echo-realworld-example-app/handler.test imports
> github.com/stretchr/testify/assert: github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.4.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/@v/v1.4.0.zip": read tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:xx->74.125.200.141:443: wsarecv: An existing connect
> ion was forcibly closed by the remote host.

But when go by browser 'https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/@v/v1.4.0.zip' it download the zip normal

This error occur in my PC in company proxy, in my PC at home it work normal.

Comment: I think as you mentioned, it will be better to check what happened in your company proxy. It seems your company proxy interrupts the connection and closes it.

Comment: I think so but go with browser still normal , may be a difference between run by browser and command?